# Selling event tickets where the attendance is limited and people can attend multiple or single days

Tags: magento-1.9, inventory

I want to be able to sell tickets for an event that runs over two days. Ideally people should be able to buy a ticket for a single day or for both days but the total places available for each day is set at a finite number.

I have set up three products (ticket-day-1, ticket-day-2, ticket-both-days) but having each ticket as a simple product doesn't work because if someone purchases a 2-day ticket it won't reduce stock on the single days. When ticket-both-days is purchased it needs to reduce stock on both ticket-day-1 and ticket-day-2.

Is there some way of doing this?

(Or am I just going to have to manually change stock levels of the single day tickets when a 2-day ticket is purchased?)

Using Magento CE 1.9.2

Comment: Did you consider making both days ticket a grouped product type?

Comment: Not sure how that would help. The event is a grouped product anyway with single day and double days tickets available? Do you mean a bundled product?